# Что не так с сервером winginx?

Tags: nginx, winginx

- Версия дистрибутива: последняя - 0.6.2 (02.03.14)
- Преднастройки: нету
- Своих настроек: не было

Установлена последняя "*чистая*" версия сегодняшним днем. В итоге "*рабочий ресурс*" открывается непонятно как:

Открываю главную страницу и она тут же скачивается на компьютер без разрешения. При попытке открыть по прямому адресу - аналогично. Но дальше еще хуже. После "*ручного*" перехода на любую другую страницу, идет перенаправление на эту страницу при попытке открыть *localhost*.

Что можно с этим сделать?

p.s.
*И только ms edge более менее нормально открыл главную страницу, но без графики. Видимо ms edge один оказался стойкиv перед тупостью этого сервера.(Оказывается он не так плох, за что спасибо microsoft)*

Comment: Сервер посылает кривые заголовки, а тупость ms edge как раз в этом и есть

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: использовать nginx =)

Comment: с обычным такая же ситуация.

Comment: выходит дело в само приложении, посмотрите список заголовков и сопоставьте с типичным набором для статического html-файла.

Comment: Извините, но у меня там простая php страничка без премудростей. В самом начале ругалось на session_start, позже проблема была решена. 
Попробовал открыть по 127 ip, описанной мной проблемы нет(ни в winginx, ни в nginx) а просто выдает 404 ошибку.

Comment: Нашел решение проблемы со скачиванием страниц. Они перестали скачиваться после удаления, забытого в файлах .htaccess
Но осталась проблема с 404 ошибкой

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.4.5
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 20:45:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 570
Connection: keep-alive
Request Headers
view parsed

Comment: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Comment: Cookie: pma_lang=ru; pma_collation_connection=utf8_general_ci; pma_mcrypt_iv=GweI3VmIRYs%3D; pmaUser-1=a6AyW7%2Bg0Sk%3D; pmaPass-1=ba%2BEVQC9BQ6JnTO1Ci%2Fmdw%3D%3D; pma_navi_width=200

Comment: Если Вы действительно пробовали настраивать nginx, to `.htaccess` ему ни каким боком. Для ngixn это просто файл

Comment: Я знаю, что он не реагирует на этот файл. Но Это как раз и странно :)